# SAP HANA Studio: Use SQLScript without writing a procedure

Tags: sql, hana

Is it possible to execute SQLScript without creating a procedure? I would like to write ad-hoc queries using cursors, but by default, the "SQL Console" within HANA Studio uses HANA SQL instead of HANA SQLScript, which does not support cursors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since HANA SP10 there is the possibility to use anonymous blocks:

DO BEGIN
-- your logic
END

http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2015/06/29/new-sqlscript-features-in-sap-hana-10-sps-10

Answer (score 1):

At least you do not need to create the procedure as hdbprocedure file.
You can type in the SQL Console e.g. the following:

```
DROP PROCEDURE test; //from previous execution
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST() 
    LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
    AS
BEGIN
--- Type your procedure code here. All features of procedures should be available
END;

CALL TEST();
```